# How to check if a Sitecore item is linked to another item

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api

Is there a way to check if an item is **linked to other items using C#**?

Also, how to remove these links?
Somehow `item.Versions.RemoveAll(false)` is not working if the item is linked to other items.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code.

1. Get the item links

```
ItemLink[] itemLinks = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item);
```

2. Programmatically find and remove item links. You need to loop them to remove links.

```
ItemLink[] itemLinks = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath));

foreach (ItemLink link in itemLinks)
{
     Sitecore.Data.Items.Item linkItem = Context.Database.GetItem(link.SourceItemID);
     if (linkItem == null) continue;

     Field field = linkItem.Fields[link.SourceFieldID];
     if (field == null) continue;

     CustomField customField = FieldTypeManager.GetField(field);
     if (customField == null) continue;

     linkItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
     customField.RemoveLink(link);
     linkItem.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to get all the items that are linked and delete them.

```
public string RemoveReferenceLinks(string nodePath)
{
    var db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    var item = db.GetItem(nodePath);

    if (item == null) return new ItemLink[0];

    var links =  Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(item, true);

    if (links.Length == 0)
    {
      return "No referrence found";
    }

    foreach (var link in links)
    {
      var sourceItem = link.GetSourceItem();

      foreach (var item1 in sourceItem.Versions.GetVersions(true))
      {

        var field = item1.Fields[link.SourceFieldID];
        var field2 = FieldTypeManager.GetField(field);

        if (field2 == null) return;

        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
          item1.Editing.BeginEdit();
          field2.RemoveLink(link);
          item1.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
      }
    }

    return "All reference removed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get reference items from Sitecore Link Database using this extension method

```
 public static Item[] GetReferrersAsItems(this Item item, bool includeStandardValues = false)
    {
        var links = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item);
        if (links == null)
            return new Item[0];
        var linkedItems = links.Select(i => i.GetSourceItem()).Where(i => i != null);
        if (!includeStandardValues)
            linkedItems = linkedItems.Where(i => !i.Name.Equals("__standard values", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        return linkedItems.ToArray();
    }
```

To retrieve the referrers simply call the `Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers` with the item passed as a parameter.

if we only want the items from within the current context site. This can be done simply by determining if an item resides beneath the current sitecontext start path.

```
public static Item[] GetReferencesInContextSite(this Item item)
    {
        var siteContext = Context.Site;
        if (siteContext == null)
            return new Item[0];
        var referrers = item.GetReferencesAsItems());
        return referrers.Where(i => i.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith(siteContext.StartPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
    }
```

[Credit Source][1]: https://laubplusco.net/sitecore-item-extensions-get-referrers-as-items/